# how to conditionally format cells with specific text containing a set of options

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I am trying to quickly sort a spreadsheet with the following countries, bringing every row that contains these countries to the top. Is there a way to conditionally format cells with specific text containing a set of options, such as specific text containing "Japan, Malaysia, Singapore, Thailand..." without having to create multiple rules per country?

Thanks for you kind reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the conditional formatting all right. You will have to create a new rule for the conditional formatting and then, try this formula on the first cell:

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1,{"Japan","Malaysia","Singapore","Thailand"},0))
```

Note, the above assumes that the country you want to conditionally format is in A1. Change as required.

Pick the formatting you wish to use before pressing 'OK' and the copy/paste the formatting on the remaining cells.

You can add more countries to the list above within the braces, quoted and separated by comma.

The above function basically checks if `A1` appears in the list. If it is, `MATCH` will return a number, and it will return an error otherwise.

`ISNUMBER` then returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` depending on whether a number was obtained or not.